# Combining map values into one json?

Tags: json, csv, go

I am in the process of learning Go and I'm trying to make a program that takes websites stored in a csv in a column. Then queries http://ip-api.com to find out what country the IP address originates from.

However the issue I am running into is my JSON is showing up like this:

```
[{"country":"Singapore"}]
[{"country":"United States"},{"country":"United States"}]
[{"country":"Singapore"},{"country":"Singapore"},{"country":"Singapore"}]
[{"country":"Ireland"},{"country":"Ireland"},{"country":"Ireland"},{"country":"Ireland"}]
```

But I want it to show up like this

```
{"country": "Singapore",
 "country": "United States"
 "country": "Ireland"
}
```

My CSV File looks like this

```
www.google.com
www.bing.com
www.pokemon.com
www.yahoo.com
```

And here is my code

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

func closeFile(f *os.File) {
    err := f.Close()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "error: %v\n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}
func main() {
    m := make(map[string]string)
    result := []map[string]string{}

    csvFile, err :=
        os.Open("test.csv")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer closeFile(csvFile)
    reader := csv.NewReader(csvFile)
    for {
        line, err := reader.Read()
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        } else if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        response, err := http.Get(fmt.Sprintf("http://ip-api.com/json/%s?fields=org", line[0]))
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            defer response.Body.Close()

        } else {
            data, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
            err := json.Unmarshal(data, &m)
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }
            result = append(result, m)
            rest, _ := json.Marshal(result)
            fmt.Println(string(rest)) **
        }

    }

}
```

I feel like the issue is I'm missing a for: range loop to compile everything before printing but I would love any feedback to sort this issue out.

Comment: The output you claim to want is not valid JSON. For one thing, keys must be quoted. For another, you cannot have duplicate keys.

Comment: Your edit removed the unquoted keys, but you still have duplicate keys, so it's still invalid JSON.

Comment: @Flimzy you can see when I marshal the map to "rest" that it returns duplicate values when i run the code. Why is that? `[{"country":"Singapore"}]
[{"country":"United States"},{"country":"United States"}]
[{"country":"Singapore"},{"country":"Singapore"},{"country":"Singapore"}]
[{"country":"Ireland"},{"country":"Ireland"},{"country":"Ireland"},{"country":"Ireland"}]`

Comment: Probably because the input has multiple values. But I don't see the input. It would be best to simplify your example to show the exact data you're trying to mess with, rather than pulling it from an API.

Comment: @Flimzy I included the text in the csv file in the question. Its just 4 lines of different websites. And line[0] refers to the first column in the csv file, which has the websites. So basically it adds the website to the api link as seen in the SprintF

Comment: I'm not talking about the CSV. That's obviously _not_ producing the JSON output you're describing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because Go `maps` have [pointer semantics](https://blog.golang.org/maps), they are not values:

> Map types are reference types, like pointers or slices.

After a `map` is created with `make` before the loop is started and is `appended` to the list within the loop, it is essentially a pointer to the same underlying data stored in the list multiple times.

Then, `Unmarshal` won't create a new map, it'll reuse the same pointer, which means overwriting the previously retrieved result.

**So, the fix**

Recreate the map on every iteration. Just move the `m := make(map[string]string)` line inside the loop, right before the API call.

Comment: Thank you this actually worked, I am surprised it was such an easy solution

Comment: @BilalJama happy to help!